# Dynamic Table and Dataset in Scheduled BigQuery Job

Tags: google-apps-script, google-bigquery

I wonder if someone can help me please.

I've been looking at the following tutorial: https://shinesolutions.com/2017/11/01/scheduling-bigquery-jobs-using-google-apps-script/

I understand the principals of the script, but I'd like to make two elements of the script dynamic.

```
function runQuery() {
  var configuration = {
    "query": {
    "useQueryCache": false,
    "destinationTable": {
          "projectId": "project",
          "datasetId": "dataset",
          "tableId": "ga_sessions_20181014"
        },
    "writeDisposition": "WRITE_TRUNCATE",
    "createDisposition": "CREATE_IF_NEEDED",
    "allowLargeResults": true,
    "useLegacySql": false,
    "query": "SELECT * FROM `project.dataset.ga_sessions_20181014`"
    }
  };

  var job = {
    "configuration": configuration
  };

  var jobResult = BigQuery.Jobs.insert(job, "grey-sort-challenge");
  Logger.log(jobResult);
}
```

These are the dates in the Source and Destination table IDs, so that this will show current day-1. i.e. ga_sessions_20181014, then ga_sessions_20181015 and so on and so forth.

Could someone tell me please, is this possible?

Many thanks and kind regards

Chris

Comment: Try `Utilities.formatDate()`

Comment: Hi |'-'| thank you for taking the time to reply. Kind Regards. Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to define a variable that holds yesterday's date and format it appropriately, then concatenate it in your configuration.

There are many ways of doing this, and as pointed out in a comment, the most straightforward is probably using [`Utilities.formatDate`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatdatedate-timezone-format). Here's an example:

```
var timeZone = 'America/Chicago';
var yesterday = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(Date.now() - 24*60*60*1000), timeZone, 'yyyyMMdd');

var configuration = {
  "query": {
  "useQueryCache": false,
  "destinationTable": {
        "projectId": "project",
        "datasetId": "dataset",
        "tableId": "ga_sessions_" + yesterday
      },
  "writeDisposition": "WRITE_TRUNCATE",
  "createDisposition": "CREATE_IF_NEEDED",
  "allowLargeResults": true,
  "useLegacySql": false,
  "query": "SELECT * FROM `project.dataset.ga_sessions_" + yesterday + "`"
  }
};
```

Comment: Hi @Henrique G. Abreu, that's great many thanks.

Kind Regards

Chris