# Javascript Unterminated string literal error

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-bigquery

I wonder whether someone could help me please.

I've been working through help I received here: [Dynamic Table and Dataset in Scheduled BigQuery Job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52811522/dynamic-table-and-dataset-in-scheduled-bigquery-job/52822941#52822941)

I've tried running the code, and I think there is an inherent problem, because when I run the code (below) I receive an error on this line:

```
 "query": "SELECT
```

The error is "Unterminated string literal"

```
    function runQuery() {

          var yesterday = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "dd-MM-yyyy'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");

          var configuration = {
          "query": {
            "useQueryCache": false,
            "destinationTable": {
                  "projectId": "project_name_obfuscated",
                  "datasetId": "project_114151_shared",
                  "tableId": "test123"
                },
            "writeDisposition": "WRITE_TRUNCATE",
            "createDisposition": "CREATE_IF_NEEDED",
            "allowLargeResults": true,
            "query": "SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT hits.page.pagePath
FROM
[project:dataset.ga_sessions_20181015] 
WHERE
REGEXP_MATCH( hits.page.pagePath, r'\?email=.*@.*\.*')),
(SELECT
hits.eventInfo.eventLabel
FROM
[project:dataset.ga_sessions_20181015] 
WHERE
hits.eventInfo.eventAction = 'end-client,role,decision')"
      }
    };

    var job = {
        "configuration": configuration
    };

    var jobResult = BigQuery.Jobs.insert(job, "project_name_obfuscated");

    var jobId = jobResult.jobReference.jobId;

    // The job might not actually be done; wait until it is marked
    // complete.
    var sleepTimeMs = 500;
    while (true) {
        Utilities.sleep(sleepTimeMs);
        sleepTimeMs *= 2;
        queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.getQueryResults(projectId, jobId, {
          "maxResults": 10000);
        if (!queryResults.jobComplete) {
          break;
        }
    }
```

I've been through various tutorials and tried adding the ' + solution so the line becomes "query": ' SELECT +

But I still can't get the script to run.

Could someone possible point out where I've gone wrong?

Many thanks and kind regards!!

Comment: you'll need to show what's after `"query": "SELECT <script continues>` because as it is, the issue is clear ... there's no closing `"` on that line - it's great how you've shown code right up to the point of failure, but what you've shown is clearly not the full extent of your actual code

Comment: It would help if we see all code instead of `unterminated string literal` :)

Comment: There's an error in the query. Log the actual SQL code this will generate to the console and try to run the code on the SQL server directly. Then you know which line of the SQL is incorrect and can look in the JS code to see which part of the configuration object is wrong. With an 'unterminated string error', I have a hunch you didn't correctly escape some strings. Keep in mind that depending on what type of database you use, you have to escape single quotes, or double quotes and other characters that have meaning in SQL.

Comment: Since `\`\`` quotes are a MySQL delimiter and `\`\`` are also the javascript string template literal, are you running this code through babel or some other ES6 transpiler for any chance? Since that might mangle `\`` into `'+'`, which will produce invalid SQL.

Comment: Hi all.

I've now included the script after the query section.

I hope this helps

Comment: Hi, I've now included the full query. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hi @AFAIK. This is how you use regex in BigQuery.

Comment: Well Then it's multiline. `"` is not terminated on line 1. Join them using ```\``` or `+` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Long_literal_strings Apps script isn't ES2015. So you can't use \`\`

Comment: Hi |'-'| That's great many thanks. I was so close, yet so far!

Kind Regards

Comment: If you managed to solve it, please, post it as a solution :)

Answer (score 1):

As the user [TheMaster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8404453/themaster) pointed out in his comment, the error comes from a badly formatted multiline string:

> Well Then it's multiline. `"` is not terminated on line 1. Join them using `\` or `+` [developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/…](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Long_literal_strings) Apps script isn't ES2015. So you can't use ``

So the code should look close to this:

```
"query": "SELECT * " +
"FROM (SELECT hits.page.pagePath " +
"FROM " +
"[project:dataset.ga_sessions_20181015] " +
"WHERE " +
"REGEXP_MATCH( hits.page.pagePath, r'\?email=.*@.*\.*')), " +
"(SELECT " +
"hits.eventInfo.eventLabel "+
"FROM " +
"[project:dataset.ga_sessions_20181015] " +
"WHERE " +
" hits.eventInfo.eventAction = 'end-client,role,decision')"
```